# SQL, подсчитать количество

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте.
Есть таблица, куда записываются пополнения баланса:

username | amount

Вася     | 101

Вася      | 15

Дима     | 26

Вова     | 3

Как можно подсчитать количество человек, которые в сумме пополнили баланс более чем на N число?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select count(username)  
from (
select username
from table 
group by username 
having sum(amount) >N
) t
```

Comment: Не думаю, что это правильно.

Comment: Да, спасибо, с телефона писал , не учел )

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from (
Select username 
from table 
group by username 
having sum(amount) >N
) X;
```